# Cross-thread operation not valid c#

Tags: c#, controls, task, invoke

my problem is `How can I assign a thread to a Control`. I did [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/296f8e39-fa62-4540-942a-26a53da0896a/threading-invokerequired) but it didn't work for me.

pls help me to find out where I'm making mistake. thx

```
private   void   frm_customerGrp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        customerContext = new Customer.CustomerEntities();

        Task T_ref = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => refreshDataGridView());

        if (T_ref.IsCompleted )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
        }

    }

delegate void Delegate_GridView();

void   refreshDataGridView()
    {
        if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired )
        {
           this.Invoke(new Delegate_GridView(refreshDataGridView)); 

        // I have error at this line       
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Task.FromResult( customerContext.Select_CustomerGrp());

        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = customerContext.Select_CustomerGrp();
        }
     }


    }
```

my error is:
`Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

If I don't use `Task` in a right way. pls give me a good `article`. thank u

Comment: While I dont use Task, DataGrid fill. but when I use Task dont fill. what should i do?!  sb help plz!!! if i did know, I never create a topic :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can only change UI using UI Thread.**
 [updating datasource have effects on UI]

Replace the line generating error with :

```
Action DoCrossThreadUIWork = () =>
{
     dataGridView1.DataSource = Task.FromResult(customerContext.Select_CustomerGrp());
};

this.BeginInvoke(DoCrossThreadUIWork);
```

Comment: While I dont use Task, DataGrid fill. but when I use Task dont fill. what should i do?!